# Prove the following identity ${(\sum_1^na_jb_j)}^2 = {(\sum_1^na^2_j)}{(\sum_1^nb^2_j)}^2-\sum_1^n\sum_1^n{(a_kb_j-a_jb_k)}^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Prove the following identity
>   $$\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j b_j\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{j=1}^n a^2_j\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^nb^2_j\right) - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=k+1}^{n}(a_{k}b_j-a_jb_{k})^2$$

How should I approach and prove this identity? My thought process currently is to expand the LHS or make the RHS equal back to the LHS, however, my algebra is a little rusty in regards to summation. It would be much appreciated if you guys can give me helpful hints and nudge me in the correct path. And do explain your steps so that I may learn the underwhelming process in proving such identities.

Comment: Start by using a small values for $n$ such as $2$ and $3$.  After working out those cases, it should be easy to see how it generalizes.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet%E2%80%93Cauchy_identity) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity).

Comment: This identity (known as the Lagrange identity) is a particular case of [the Binet-Cauchy identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet%E2%80%93Cauchy_identity), which in turn is a particular case of [the Cauchy-Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) for determinants of matrix products. This is also explained in Example 6.39 of [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, version of 10 January 2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10).

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
&\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2\right)-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i\right)^2\\
=&\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_i^2b_j^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_ib_ia_jb_j\\
=&\frac12\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(a_i^2b_j^2+a_j^2b_i^2-2a_ib_ia_jb_j\right)\\
=&\frac12\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2\\
=&\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(a_{i}b_j-a_jb_{i})^2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to start with
$$ \sum_{k,j} (a_k b_j - a_j b_k)^2, $$
expand the brackets, and then split the $$ a_k^2 b_j^2 $$ terms from the $a_jb_j a_k b_k$ ones. And use that
$$ \sum_{i,j} f(i) g(j) = \left( \sum_i f(i) \right) \left( \sum_j g(j) \right). $$

Answer (score 1):

We will prove this in the following form:
  \begin{equation*}
     \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=k+1}^{n}(a_{i}b_j-a_jb_{i})^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_k\right)^2=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k^2\right)
 \end{equation*}

We make the proof by induction on n.
 Checking for $n=3$ and $n=2$.
  Note that if we define $\displaystyle \vec u=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $\displaystyle \vec v=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$, we get:

$\\ \\ \displaystyle \left| \vec u \times \vec v\right|= \left| \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\vec i & \vec j  &  \vec k \\ 
 a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
 b_1 & b_2  & b_3
\end{array} \right|\right|=\sqrt{(a_2b_1-a_1b_2)^2+(a_2c_1-a_1c_2)^2+(b_2c_1-b_1c_2)^2}\\ \\$

Hence it follows that:

\begin{equation}
    \left| \vec u \times \vec v\right|^2=(a_2b_1-a_1b_2)^2+(a_2c_1-a_1c_2)^2+(b_2c_1-b_1c_2)^2
\end{equation}

On the other hand, we get:

\begin{equation}
     \vec u.\vec v = a_1a_2+b_1b_2+c_1c_2
 \end{equation}

And this implies:

\begin{align}
     (a_2b_1-a_1b_2)^2+(a_2c_1-a_1c_2)^2+(b_2c_1-b_1c_2)^2+( a_1a_2+b_1b_2+c_1c_2)^2= \left| \vec u \times \vec v\right|^2+(\vec u.\vec v)^2
 \end{align}

Multiplying and dividing the above expression by $\displaystyle (|\vec u||\vec v|)^2$, we get:

\begin{equation}
     (a_2b_1-a_1b_2)^2+(a_2c_1-a_1c_2)^2+(b_2c_1-b_1c_2)^2+( a_1a_2+b_1b_2+c_1c_2)^2= (|\vec u||\vec v|)^2\left(\frac{\left| \vec u \times \vec v\right|^2}{(|\vec u||\vec v|)^2}+\frac{(\vec u.\vec v)^2}{(|\vec u||\vec v|)^2}\right)
 \end{equation}

Let be $\displaystyle \theta$ the angle between the vectors $\displaystyle \vec u$ and $\displaystyle \vec v$. Note that $\displaystyle \sin (\theta)=\frac{|\vec u \times \vec v|}{|\vec u| |\vec v|}$ and $\displaystyle \cos(\theta)=\frac{\vec u . \vec v}{|\vec u| |\vec v|}$, we get:

\begin{equation}
     (a_2b_1-a_1b_2)^2+(a_2c_1-a_1c_2)^2+(b_2c_1-b_1c_2)^2+( a_1a_2+b_1b_2+c_1c_2)^2= (|\vec u||\vec v|)^2\left(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta\right)
 \end{equation}

Using that $\displaystyle \sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$ for all real theta , we get:

\begin{equation}
     (a_2b_1-a_1b_2)^2+(a_2c_1-a_1c_2)^2+(b_2c_1-b_1c_2)^2+( a_1a_2+b_1b_2+c_1c_2)^2= (|\vec u||\vec v|)^2
 \end{equation}

Using that $\displaystyle |\vec u|=\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2} $ and  $\displaystyle |\vec v|=\sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2} $, it follows that:

\begin{equation}
     (a_2b_1-a_1b_2)^2+(a_2c_1-a_1c_2)^2+(b_2c_1-b_1c_2)^2+( a_1a_2+b_1b_2+c_1c_2)^2= (a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2)
 \end{equation}

And it checks the base case.

As induction hypothesis, suppose the equality below is valid for a given $n$:

\begin{equation}
     \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=k+1}^{n}(a_{i}b_j-a_jb_{i})^2+(a_1b_1+...+a_nb_n)^2=(a^2_1+...+a^2_n)(b^2_1+...+b^2_n) \tag{1}
 \end{equation}

Note that
 \begin{equation*}
     (a_1b_1+...+a_nb_n)a_{n+1}b_{n+1}+(a_1b_1+...+a_nb_n+a_{n+1}b_{n+1})a_{n+1}b_{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_{n+1}b_k-a_kb_{n+1})^2=
 \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation}
     (a^2_{n+1}b^2_1+...+a^2_{n+1}b^2_n)+(a^2_1b^2_{n+1}+...+a^2_{n}b^2_{n+1})+a^2_{n+1}b^2_{n+1} \tag{2}
 \end{equation}

Adding the left side of ( 2) with the left side of ( 1 ) and adding the right hand side of ( 2) with the right hand side of ( 1 ), we get:

\begin{equation*}
     \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=k+1}^{n}(a_{i}b_j-a_jb_{i})^2+(a_1b_1+...+a_{n+1}b_{n+1})^2+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_{n+1}b_k-a_kb_{n+1})^2=
 \end{equation*}
 \begin{equation*}
    (a^2_1+...+a^2_n)(b^2_1+...+b^2_n)+(a^2_{n+1}b^2_1+...+a^2_{n+1}b^2_n)+(a^2_1b^2_{n+1}+...+a^2_{n}b^2_{n+1})+a^2_{n+1}b^2_{n+1}=
 \end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    (a^2_1+...+a^2_n)(b^2_1+...+b^2_n)+a^2_{n+1}(b^2_1+...+b^2_n)+b^2_{n+1}(a^2_1+...+a^2_{n}+a^2_{n+1})=
 \end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    (a^2_1+...+a^2_n+a^2_{n+1})(b^2_1+...+b^2_n)+b^2_{n+1}(a^2_1+...+a^2_{n}+a^2_{n+1})=
 \end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    (a^2_1+...+a^2_n+a^2_{n+1})(b^2_1+...+b^2_n+b^2_{n+1})\Rightarrow
 \end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
     \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=k+1}^{n}(a_{i}b_j-a_jb_{i})^2+(a_1b_1+...+a_{n+1}b_{n+1})^2+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_{n+1}b_k-a_kb_{n+1})^2=
 \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
    (a^2_1+...+a^2_n+a^2_{n+1})(b^2_1+...+b^2_n+b^2_{n+1})\Rightarrow
 \end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
     \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=k+1}^{n+1}(a_{i}b_j-a_jb_{i})^2+(a_1b_1+...+a_{n+1}b_{n+1})^2=
 \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
    (a^2_1+...+a^2_n+a^2_{n+1})(b^2_1+...+b^2_n+b^2_{n+1})\Rightarrow
 \end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
     \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=k+1}^{n+1}(a_{i}b_j-a_jb_{i})^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}a_kb_k\right)^2=
 \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
    \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}a_k^2\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}b_k^2\right)
 \end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

It is the usual generalization of [Lagrange's four squares identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_four-square_theorem) that can be used to prove Cauchy-Schwarz' inequality. In the LHS we have terms of the type $a_j^2 b_j^2$ or $a_j b_j a_i b_i$ only, we just need to check that they appear in the RHS with the same multiplicity.

The identity also follows from:
$$ |v\times w|^2 + |v\cdot w|^2 = |v|^2 |w|^2(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta) = |v|^2 |w|^2 $$
with $v=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $w=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$.