# Lagrange's identity

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

How to prove Lagrange's identity?

\begin{equation*}
     \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=k+1}^{n}(a_{k}b_j-a_jb_{k})^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_k\right)^2=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k^2\right)
 \end{equation*}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove the following identity ${(\sum_1^na_jb_j)}^2 = {(\sum_1^na^2_j)}{(\sum_1^nb^2_j)}^2-\sum_1^n\sum_1^n{(a_kb_j-a_jb_k)}^2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459715/prove-the-following-identity-sum-1na-jb-j2-sum-1na2-j-sum-1n)